# Pandas how to fillna in place on a column?

Tags: python, pandas

After running:

```
df[['column']].fillna(value=myValue, inplace=True)
```

or:

```
df['column'].fillna(value=myValue, inplace=True)
```

or:

```
# Throws warning "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice..."
df.fillna({'column': myValue}, inplace=True)
```

or:

```
df[['column']] = df[['column']].fillna({'column': myValue})
```

or:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].fillna({'column': myValue})
```

My `df['column']` still contains `nan` (!)

`list(df['column'].unique())` returns `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', nan]` and `sum(pd.isnull(df['column']))` returns 1,000+.

I've tried several variations but this problem persists. How do you fillna in place on a column in pandas?

Comment: shouldn't it be `df['column'].fillna(value=myValue, inplace=True)`?, what you wrote works on a view on your df as a single column which probably is why it failed. OK so now what you've posted should work but without data and code to reproduce your issue, this becomes a guessing game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ed Chum's comment's correctly points out the difference between the methods you propoosed. Here is an example I used to show how it works.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [3, 4, np.nan, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df
```

```
   col1  col2
0     1   3.0
1     2   4.0
2     3   NaN
3     4   NaN
```

```py
df['col2'].fillna(value=6, inplace=True)
```

```
   col1  col2
0     1   3.0
1     2   4.0
2     3   6.0
3     4   6.0
```

Having posted this, I think it'd be most valuable to see what your `my_value` variable's value is and what your dataframe looks like.

I discard Aditya's hypothesis. In the case the nan would be a string, it would appear between quotations marks, and it doesn't.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for helping me walk through that issue. I was initially filling the values with a calculated `mean`, which I later switched to a `mode`. I now see that a mode needs to have an `axis`.

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this problem can be that the nan values in your dataset might be the string 'nan' instead of NaN.
To solve this, you can use the replace() method instead of fillna().

Eg code:

```
df['column'].replace(to_replace='nan',value=myValue,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the correct syntax from your list is

```
df['column'].fillna(value=myValue, inplace=True)
```

If `list(df['column'].unique())` returns `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', nan]`, this means that the values in your dataset are probably not equal to `np.NaN`, but rather equal to the string "nan".